# How to use case when in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to use `case` after `where` clause in SQL Server 2008; how can I use it like

```
select * 
from MPR 
where
    case when @min >= 0 
           then MainComponent_Id = @mainc and SubComponent_Id = @subcomp 
           else MainComponent_Id = @mainc and SubComponent_Id = @subcomp and MinorComponent_Id = @minorc   
   end
end
```

I am using a stored procedure, and in my stored procedure if `minorcomponent_id` value is 0 then it will add 1 one else 2 one will work.

I had tried hard but its giving error in near case.

How to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a `CASE` statement. You can simplify logic as follows:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    MPR 
where
    MainComponent_Id = @mainc AND SubComponent_Id = @subcomp
    AND (@min >= 0 OR MinorComponent_Id = @minorc)
```